# Automatic Type Conversion with extension: What is happening here?

Tags: swift

I'm going through the first chapter of `The Swift Programming Language` book and I'm at the part where it's describing the `extension` keyword.

I had a go at the "Experiment":

> “Write an extension for the Double type that adds an absoluteValue property.”

I got it working like this:

```
extension Double {
    var absoluteValue: Double {
        if(self < 0) {
            return self * -1
        }

        return self
    }
}

(-10.5).absoluteValue    // 10.5
```

But it also seems to work for integers:

```
(-4).absoluteValue       // 4.0
```

What is happening here? Is the compiler changing the type from `Int` to `Double` because it sees that there is a `absoluteValue` extension on `Double` but not `Int`?

This appears to be the case because if I add another `extension` of the same name on `Int` like so:

```
extension Int {
    var absoluteValue: Int {
        return 42
    }
}
```

That overrides the `extension` on `Double`. And `(-4).absoluteValue` returns `42`

Is there a way to add an `extension` that *only* works on `Double`s but not `Int`s?

Edit: Looks like it's doing a conversion at compile-time and since I didn't define a type for my literal it converted it. The following produces an error

```
var i:Int = -4;
i.absoluteValue
```

> "Playground execution failed: error: :12:1: error: 'Int' does not have a member named 'absoluteValue'
>   i.absoluteValue
>   ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~"

Edit 2: It appears to only apply to literals; the following also produces an error:

```
var i = -4;
i.absoluteValue
```

Comment: Just curious, is it the swift that Apple just announced?

Comment: @AD.Net - yes, figured I'd give it a go this afternoon and start playing around with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the extension you wrote is actually only for `Double`s, not for `Int`s. Take a look at this example:

```
extension Double {
    var absoluteValue: Double {
        if (self < 0) {
            return self * -1
        }

        return self
    }
}

var double: Int = 10
double.absoluteValue // Int does not have a member named absoluteValue
```

But, in your code the compiler is implicitly converting your `Int` to a `Double`.

Comment: Found this later on in the book; same thing appears to apply here: “The rules for combining numeric constants and variables are different from the rules for numeric literals. The literal value 3 can be added directly to the literal value 0.14159, because _number literals do not have an explicit type in and of themselves_. Their type is inferred only at the point that they are evaluated by the compiler.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: this is a little less wordier than creating a variable `Int(-2).absoluteValue`

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone would like an answer that conforms to the example protocol:

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String { get }
    mutating func adjust()
}

extension Double: ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String {
        return "The number \(self)"
    }
    var absoluteValue: Double {
        return fabs(self)
    }
    mutating func adjust() {
        self = round(self)
    }
}
var double: Double = -12.34
double.simpleDescription
double.absoluteValue
```